# What kind of spelling error is using "are" in the place of "our"?

Tags: orthography, homophones

It's using the homophone but is there a name for that kind of spelling error in Child Writing Acquisition? The whole phrase is:

> After that we Played with **are** inten 
>   do will".

Of course there are several other errors in this!

(This is in relation to my English Language course)

Comment: I like the creative way of writing "Nintendo Wii" :), but I also believe the child capitalizes the stresses, which is unusual.

Comment: What is Child Writing Acquisition?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Looking back at the source, it isn't clear whether the 'll' at the end of Wii are capital 'i's or lowercase 'l's.

Comment: But the child did mean "Nintendo Wii" ? I would add that as a footnote in your question, and explain what "Child Writing Acquisition" is. I think in my day it was simply called "writing" and "spelling" :)

Comment: I suppose it's a homophonic mistranslation, but I like to call them Mondegreens, especially when they're funny. (Technically a Mondegreen involves song lyrics, but I haven't found a better general term.)

Comment: Just as an aside, I note that, in Pirate-speak, "Arrrr, arr arrs arr arrrnj" means "I say, our oars are orange."

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it a [malapropism](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+malapropism), the use of an incorrect word in place of a word with a similar sound resulting in a nonsensical utterance. In a strict sense, a malapropism occurs in spoken language. Also, we tend to think of them as humorous as in these written and spoken examples provided by [Melissa Bowersock](http://www.indiesunlimited.com/2015/06/09/malapropisms-writing-the-wrong-word/). Still, it's the aptest term of which I know for substituting 'are' and 'our' since it's a nonsensical usage that arises from a similarity of sound.